# html conditional comment for iOS

Tags: html, conditional-comments

I am trying to use a conditional comment to check for iOS (like `<!--[if IE 9>…` but for an iPhone or mobile device. Any help? and I am NOT asking for CSS or JavaScript

Comment: There are no conditional comments for iOS, only IE < 10.

Comment: Ok thanks. Thats what I was wanting to know. Is there a way using html to get that information other than conditional comments?

Comment: HTML is markup only. It doesn't do anything. IE conditional comments are the closest it ever came to being dynamic. What is your actual problem? Maybe it can be solved properly.

Comment: I am just trying to make a mobile version of my site and I saw the conditional comments for IE and thought it was really easy. So I just wanted to know if there was something like that for iOS

Comment: My advice would be to use CSS media queries to change the styling to work on iOS.